# In Powershell, how to copy files with common file name string (i.e. "ABC*") last written in a specific date range?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, from folder "C:\folderSource" to folder "D:\folderDestination" how to copy files with common file name string (i.e. "ABC*") that were last written in specific date range (i.e. September 20, 2016 to October 10, 2017)?  I have tried different ways, but not successful yet.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have any work to show? What part exactly are you stuck at? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you need help learning how to code or troubleshoot something then this is the place for you. If you need code from scratch then you should hire a developer.

Comment: Could you please post the code so we could inspect and try to solve together with you? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common task, here's the general approach we take to solving an issue like this in PowerShell.

1. Get a list of files, VMs, Items, ETC
2. Pipe this into the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter and apply one or more constraints
3. That's it!

With your requirements, we'll actually do Step 2 in two separate steps, to highlight the approach needed.   I choose a different date range (From Sept 1 ~ Sept 30) but once you understand the concepts, you'll know how to change this to fit your needs.  To start things off, here is the directory I'm testing against (pay close attention to the `LastWriteTime` column).

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                           
-a----        9/22/2017   3:40 PM          64307 AcfBIns.jpg                                                                                    
-a----        9/23/2017  10:15 PM           7047 beer-mug_1f37a.png                                                                             
-a----        6/30/2017  12:15 PM          63304 bg.png                                                                                         
-a----        9/20/2017  10:07 AM            938 certnew (1).p7b                                                                                
-a----         6/1/2017  12:42 PM            822 DistributeMe.cer                                                                               
-a----        7/27/2017   3:38 PM          95234 EFIESP.png                                                                                     
-a----         7/5/2017   2:37 PM        1920416 Encoding Time.csv                                                                              
-a----        9/22/2017   3:46 PM       66932648 en_remote_tools_for_visual_studio_2015.exe                               
-a----        5/26/2017  12:31 PM            306 F0X_PPKG_PROD.cat                                                                              
-a----        5/26/2017  12:31 PM           5529 F0X_PPKG_PROD.ppkg                                                                             
-a----        6/23/2017   3:29 PM          50541 Fox.jpg                                                                                        
-a----         7/8/2017   1:20 AM          10240 GetStats.exe                                                                                   
-a----       10/12/2017   9:49 AM         126868 GIF.gif                                                                                        
-a----        9/21/2017   9:28 AM       10427442 giphy (1).gif
```

First, a baseline of my folder to see how many items are there.

```
dir C:\source | measure | select Count
>Count : 14
```

Now, for Step 2, building a filter: I'll start by making a pointer to my earliest file start date, using the `Get-Date` cmdlet.  This will give me an 'earliest file age' to compare against.

```
$Sept1  = Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 09 -Day 01
```

Here's the cool part, I can *filter* the files by looking only for ones Modified AFTER the date contained in `$Sept1` with one simple command, the `Where-Object` cmdlet.  In DotNet terms, Greater Than refers to after a date, while Lesser Than refers to taking place before a date.

```
dir c:\source | where LastWriteTime -ge $Sept1 | measure | select Count
> Count : 6
```

After applying the first half of the filter, I have a list of only files modified beginning with September 1st.  You can then add an additional `Where-Object` command to narrow down to just your desired timespan like so:

```
#Make a pointer to the end of Sept
$Sept30 = Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 09 -Day 30
dir c:\source | where LastWriteTime -ge $Sept1 |
    Where LastWriteTime -le $Sept30 | measure | select Count

>Count : 5
```

Now, just modify the dates to match your timespan and I think you can get this problem solved.

#### Older versions of PowerShell

Did you get an error like `"cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the 'LastWriteTime" value of type System.String to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"`, if so, then try this syntax instead.

```
 $Sept30 = Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 09 -Day 30 
 dir \\0.0.0.100\C$\source | where {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $Sept1} | 
   where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $Sept30} | measure | select Count
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm giving it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried it. I should have mentioned that my source folder and destination are unc  paths.  For example, \\0.0.0.100\C$\Source and \\10.10.0.200\D$\Destination

Comment: I tried the following:                                                                        
 $Sept30 = Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 09 -Day 30
dir \\0.0.0.100\C$\source | where LastWriteTime -ge $Sept1 |
where LastWriteTime -le $Sept30 | measure | select Count                  
But got this message,  "cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'.  Cannot convert the 'LastWriteTime" value of type System.String to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"

Comment: OH, sounds like you're on the older version of PowerShell, try the modified syntax.